# Can I square off a uPVC door sill which is inside a conservatory?

Tags: doors, door-frame, laminate-floor, laminate

I have a uPVC door between a dining room and a conservatory. On the conservatory side there is the uPVC sill, this sill is inside the conservatory and the existing tiles match up to the edge of the sill nicely.

I am laying laminate down on top of the tiles in the conservatory, the combined height of the tiles, underlay, and laminate would mean the laminate would come slightly over the lip of the uPVC sill and create a messy edge to finish.

I am planning to cut the uPVC sill out with a multi-tool at the base of the door frame and square off the sill so the laminate would be able to finish neatly at the base of the door frame where I can then apply a wood bead between the laminate and frame.

Would taking out a portion of the sill affect the integrity of the uPVC frame?

[image]

Comment: are you aware that the sill is hollow?

Comment: Yes I am aware that it is hollow in places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with a local UPVC firm they explained that trimming off the front portion of the sill will not have any damaging effect on the structure of the door overall. The door sits on the sill but the jam (frame) is securely screwed into the walls, which is where it gets the majority of it's integrity from.

Trimming the sill:
[image]

Laying the laminate:
[image]

Finished with a UPVC trim:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for coming back to answer your question and showing pics of what you did. I remember seeing this question when you originally asked it, and I had the same thoughts as everyone who'd answered - that you were cutting just the edge off. If you'd drawn a line on your original pic showing where you were planning on cutting, you may have gotten different answers. You did the best thing possible, though, in contacting a local manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the exposed end of the sill, that looks like a terrible idea.

It appears to be an extrusion with a few ribs and void spaces between ribs, not a solid block. If you cut off the edge, you'll have an unsupported "flap" sticking out from the next rib. That seems unlikely to wear well.

Comment: The idea would be to cut at the base of the door frame or even a bit further back if possible. There's then a few options...I could finish the cut edge with a flat piece of uPVC trim to create a 90 degree for the laminate to finish against or lay the laminate past the bottom of the door frame and use a wood bead between the laminate and door frame. You can make anything look good with the right materials, I'm more concerned about whether cutting away that sill will adversely affect the integrity of the door frame.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Ecnerwal, do not square it off by cutting it.

If you insist on installing laminate on top of the tile  then the best way to address the transition is with a transition strip. (*such as one used in doorways to transition between two different flooring products.*)

A [thin metal](https://www.lowes.com/pd/M-D-1-375-in-x-96-in-Carpet-Trim/4776411) one would be best and it will be easier to drill through the pvc sill to fasten it as apposed to drilling through the very hard tile.

You could try a [J type channel](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Schluter-Systems-0-25-in-x-98-5-in-Brushed-Chrome-Anodized-Aluminum-Floor-Transition/1001381194) but that would only work if the laminate was level of lower than the PVC sill. It would require drilling through the tile and Laminate needs a gap for expansion and contraction so it may not have enough coverage for the gap.

Comment: I have edited my question, I'm more concerned about whether cutting away part of the sill will have any adverse effects on the integrity of the uPVC door/frame.

Comment: As Ecnerwal  explained; Cutting the hollow sill will compromise The sill's structural integrity. Are you saying you are concerned about the Door itself or the  door frame (jamb)?

Comment: I'm concerned about whether cutting away a portion of the sill will have an effect on the entire door. The door rests upon the sill, but is also secured in many places to the wall via screws though the frame. Will removing a portion of the sill result in the entire door becoming adversely affected?

Comment: @SteWoo -  I can not say, the door jamb is mounted to the walls but the door itself is on a track that is part of, molded into, the sill. Will cutting a little off of  it cause catastrophic failure? Probably not BUT, Not a good idea to mess with it. Plus it will look terrible, May be a flooring issue down the road or even effect selling the house and May? be flagged by a home inspector.